# Can I make IServiceProvider.GetService return implementations for interfaces

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have an Dependancy Injection setup where I register a service called `MyClass` that implements `MyInterface` as follows:

```
ServiceCollection.AddSingleton<MyClass>();
```

I then create an IServiceProvider by calling the extension method `BuildServiceProvider` on the `ServiceCollection`.

How can I make the `IServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyInterface>()` return an instantiated singleton instance of `MyClass`? Currently it returns null.

Comment: I build the ServiceCollection and register all my deps, then I call BuildServiceProvider on the ServiceCollection to get a IServiceProvider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default container implementation does that when the implementation is registered for being returned for that interface:

```
ServiceCollection.AddSingleton<MyInterface, MyClass>();
```

This is the preferred way of registering services, so all components requiring it require the interface and not the implementation.

Other container implementations (AutoFac) also support automatic registration for implemented interfaces (e.g. `.AsImplementedInterfaces()`) but the above code snipped is supposed to work for all containers supporting the ASP.NET Core DI abstractions.

Comment: I know that I can register the interface explicitly, but in my situation I'm wanting to get all services that conform to the interface, not that were registered against it which only works with a single interface.

Comment: I've migrated the IoC container to an AutoFac based implementation in my application, which allows me to used the .AsImplementedInterfaces() you mentioned. AutoFac provides a lot more customization than the default dotnet core containers which works well for me.